# How to get field value from jpa Entity annotate with lombook annotations?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, lombok

I have Entity class annotated with **lombook** annotation (https://projectlombok.org/features/all):

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder

@Entity
@Table(name = "members")
public class Member implements Serializable {
    private final static long serialVersionUID= 1l;
    @id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id", unique = true)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="name")
    @NonNull
    private String name;
    @Column(name="photo")
    @NonNull
    private String photo;
    @Column(name="descriotion")
    private String descriotion;
    @Column(name="winner_in_period")
    private String winnerInPeriod;
    @Column(name="created_date")
    private Date createdDate;
    @Column(name="deleted")
    private Boolean deleted;
}
```

And I have service which gives me data from the database using this Entity.
Finally I try to get some data from Member object

```
    List<Member> lastMembers = memberService.getMembers(0, lastMembersCount);

    if(lastMembers != null)
        lastMembers.forEach(member -> {
            System.out.println(member.[IN THIS PLACE I DONT HAWE ANY GETTERS for table field]);
        });
```

But I don't have any getters in Member object. When I write `member.getName()` I have error(IDEA suggested me to create getter 'getName()').
How to use lombook with jpa entity?
How to access to field which was marked with **lombok** annotations like **@Getter** or **@Setter**?

Comment: What do you mean, you don't have any getters? You should have a `public String getName()`.

Comment: (Also, you're spamming creation annotations, and there's no reason at all to have either `@RequiredArgsConstructor` or `@Builder`.)

Comment: Sorry all compiled and work!!! But IDEA still highlight getName()  as error.(I instaled plugin for lombok)  Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Your problem is unrelated to JPA. Try a simple class with a single field and `@Getter`. For the mapping, use some naming strategy instead of being explicit with every field. I guess, `@NonNull` could be a problem as it's a strict check throwing an NPE whenever violated. You should use something like `@Basic(optional=false)`, so your columns are NOT NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use 'lombok' you should install IDEA plugin and restart IDEA. After this simple steps, all will work nicely. **Lombok** is amazing

Answer (score 0):

Enable "annotation processing".

```
Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation Processor: Enable annotation processing
```